# Sample Design for Call Centre

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, sample-size, proportion, sample

I'm working on a research project for a call centre, it's been a while since I have done any applied statistics so I could really use some help. Here's what I want to do:

I need to understand why customers are calling into the call centre so I can design an appropriate queuing and prioritisation strategy. I plan on asking agents to listen to a sample of calls and categorise those calls. There is currently no data on why customers are calling in, so there is uncertainty around the number of potential call categories.

I need to understand two things:
a) How I should design my sampling strategy.
b) What are suitable approaches for wrapping confidence intervals around the category proportions to make an inference about the population of calls?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Both questions are premature.  You need a preliminary study just to understand what the call categories might be, how to measure and record properties of the calls, and to begin framing the questions you wish to answer with your project.

Comment: On your point about call categories I thought this might be the case, wouldn't this still involve some sample design though? Given we have no data on call categories, but we have recorded calls we could look back and wok out categories, but we would still need to take a sample of these recordings...

Comment: There are likely more efficient ways to gather preliminary information.  Talking to a call center manager would, of course, yield *anecdotes,* not data, but these anecdotes could be extremely useful for designing a small preliminary study, intended to yield some objective quantitative information useful for a larger scale study. You have to do these kinds of projects in stages rather than all at once, because you need to learn as you go.  Formal statistical sample design, sampling, and statistical testing (including confidence intervals) are all at the end stages of the process.

Comment: The preliminary study would give some idea about categories. Once we have that information how should we execute the formal study?